# Problem using default pages in Experience Manager

Tags: 2011, experience-manager, content-delivery

We have discovered that when we use the URLs without filenames in our web application, that is, using the default filenames of the server (welcome file list in Tomcat), Experience Manager doesn't work properly, as the temporary files with local changes don't appear in the file system.

Has anybody faced this problem before?

Comment: Interesting one. I guess linking is failing to determine the page URI because the URLs don't match. I can't really see an easy way out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have seen a similar issue to this in an IIS based .NET application - to work around it I wrote an `HTTPModule` which detected directory requests and re-wrote them to

```
 ../path/index.aspx
```

This module is only installed on the staging server for obvious reasons. You may be able to write similar functionality as a Java Filter to work around the problem, although I suspect this is a bug, and you should submit a ticket to customer support.

Comment: Yes I have done a java servlet filter with a similar workaround, looping through the welcome file list but I think it's not too elegant, and I've submitted a ticket to Tridion. Thanks

Comment: I agree - it is not elegant, but I can't think of a better work around - Good luck with the support request

Answer (score 3):

This scenario is totally covered by hotfix `CD_2011.1.1.84669`. You only need to create your own claim processor which, in case of requests for `'/'` (or whatever your path is), sets the following claims: `'taf:session:preview:request:full_url'` to `'/index.jsp'` (or whatever your welcome file is) and `'taf:session:preview:request:real_path'` to `'<webroot>\index.jsp'`.

Comment: But, that hotfix is not available yet, no?

Comment: You are right. It was released a week ago. You need to contact Customer Support to make sure they make it available for you.